# Time complexity issue in text mining code

Tags: python, performance, text-mining

I Have 30 million posts, and 600 queries representing 600 brands.
For example the query `"Harry Potter" OR "Harry"` represent the brand Harry Potter,
and the post can be:

```
Yesterday I went to see harry potter. The movie was great!
```

I have the class `Post` representing the post text, and also include functions that handle the operation of finding a term (`"Harry"`, `"Harry Potter"`) in the post text.
Another class is `Query`, representing the query, and communicates with `Post`.
I ran the code over 100K posts, and it took half an hour.

```
class Post:

    def __init__(self, post):
        self._postString = post
        self._postString = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', self._postString)
        self._parsedSen = self._postString.split(' ')
        self._length = len(self._parsedSen)


    def isTermAppear(self, term):
        k = None
        termArr = term.split(' ')
        for i in range(self._length):
            if i + len(termArr) <= len(self._parsedSen):
                k = i
                flag = True
                for j in range(len(termArr)):
                    if not self._parsedSen[k].lower().find(termArr[j].lower()) >= 0:
                        flag = False
                    k += 1
                if flag:
                    return True
        return False
```

Then I change the function to be trivial, and ran the code again. This time it took 3 minutes.

```
def isTermAppear(self, term):
    return False
```

How can `Post` be more efficient?

Comment: This question might perhaps be a better fit for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You want ElasticSearch

Answer (score 1):

Store the lower case of the target words in `self._parsedSen` and use `termArr = term.lower().split(' ')` then use:

```
def isTermAppear(self, term):
    termArr = term.lower().split(' ')
    flag = True
    for t in termArr:
        flag &= t in self._parsedSen
    return flag
```

You will be amazed.

Comment: What's wrong with `return all(t in self._parsedSen for t in termArr)`? Your `&=` doesn't short-circuit.

Comment: @Steve Barnes as I understand your solution on a term as `"Harry Potter"`, if `Harry` and `Potter` appears in the post, not necessarily adjacent then `isTermAppear` will return true. This is fine only when `Harry Potter` appears adjacent.